# "." after a java class' name

Tags: java, android, syntax

```
public static class RelativeLayout.LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
```

I came along RelativeLayout in android studio. In order to set some parameters for a container we create an object of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. Since the dot operator can't be used in a java class' name, so why has it been used here, or is it something else. Please somebody help me on this.

Comment: That statement is not valid Java. Where did you see that statement?

Comment: @Andreas refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: Ahhh,,,, That is documentation shorthand for showing a nested class, as explained by Joe C below.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [nested class] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). In this case, `LayoutParams` is a class declared inside the `RelativeLayout` class.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` operator is used to specify a class' member - in this case, an inner class.

So, here you have a static inner class called `LayoutParams` which is an inner class of `RelativeLayout` and extends the static inner class `MarginLayoutParams` of `ViewGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nested class and nested classes can be defined like that. For your instance:

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams is a nested class of RelativeLayout.

Example of nested class:

```
class OuterClass {
   ...
class NestedClass {
    ...
   }
}
```

Info on nested classes:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, like all other classes, is a class because of its declaration:

```
public static class RelativeLayout.LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams 
{

....
}
```

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams is still a class, no meter if you create an object from it or not.